# Why does the "and" become an "or" in this question?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

Question: Which of the following represents ¬A if A stands for " I like reading but I hate running".

My answer was:

¬A = I hate reading but I like running.

The actual answer:

¬A = I either hate reading or I like running.

I am confused to why the "and" was changed to an "or". Did the negation change the "and" to an "or"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement $A$ is the same as "I like reading and I hate running", which is the intersection or conjunction of two different statements: $B$, which is "I like reading" and $C$, which is "I hate running", therefore $A = B \land C$. Using De Morgan Laws (I don't know if you know them), $ ¬A = ¬ (B \land C) = ¬ B \lor ¬ C$, which means exactly the same as the solution you expose here.

Comment: To piggy-back on this, DeMorgan's Laws are hopefully totally intuitive even if you haven't studied them explicitly yet. How can you make the statement "I have a pen and a calculator" false? Either you don't have a pen *or* you don't have a calculator.